# Accurev Promotion - Issue Dependencies

Tags: accurev

My company uses Accurev for source control, and for all its benefits, there's one simple action that I just can't figure out how to accomplish.

I wanted to promote an issue#A from Development stream to UAT stream. But issue#A am trying to promote has dependency on another earlier Issue#B. Now when am trying to promote issue#A am getting “Operation Failed: merge required for Element: xxxyyy.java.

Please help me in how to promote issue#A to UAT stream from Development Stream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, It sounds like the file xxxyyy.java is in an overlap state and needs merging, thus the error.

If issueA has a dependency on issueB, you should probably promote both issues as there is a common file between the two issues.

Example:
Keep and promote file1 -> associate issueA
keep and promote file1 -> associate issueB

You can promote issueA by itself as the version of file1 is 1.
You can not promote issueB by itself as the version of file1 is 2 and it contains version 1 (issueA, the dependent issue.)